# What functions should I use for the Options price in my Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance, google-finance

The GOOGLEFINANCE does only stock price but I want to import Options price using any functions in Google sheets?

[I've tried this Yahoo Finance using appscript but the price only shows once the market opens, it's kinda bummer cuz it show zero in my sheets and it makes the calculations go wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXtV1.png)